# Merge similar PSObjects from an array

Tags: powershell

I have the following array with similar PSObjects :

```
PS C:\Test\$events

total events
----- ------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  867 {@{category_id=1; content_ver=Version: 2022-10-26 rev. 008; Sequence: 221026008; count=1; cybox=; device_end_time=1666837251000; device_ip=X.X.X.X; device_location=; device_time=1666837251000; feature_name=MALWARE_PROTECTION; feature_ui… 
  867 {@{category_id=1; content_ver=Version: 2022-10-30 rev. 003; Sequence: 221030003; count=1; cybox=; device_end_time=1667163237000; device_ip=X.X.X.X; device_location=; device_time=1667163237000; feature_name=MALWARE_PROTECTION; feature_uid=… 
  867 {@{category_id=1; content_ver=Version: 2022-10-30 rev. 003; Sequence: 221030003; count=1; cybox=; device_end_time=1667163237000; device_ip=X.X.X.X; device_location=; device_time=1667163237000; feature_name=MALWARE_PROTECTION; feature_uid=… 
  867 {@{category_id=1; content_ver=Version: 2022-10-30 rev. 003; Sequence: 221030003; count=1; cybox=; device_end_time=1667163237000; device_ip=X.X.X.X; device_location=; device_time=1667163237000; feature_name=MALWARE_PROTECTION; feature_uid=… 
  867 {@{category_id=1; content_ver=Version: 2022-10-30 rev. 003; Sequence: 221030003; count=1; cybox=; device_end_time=1667163237000; device_ip=X.X.X.X; device_location=; device_time=1667163237000; feature_name=MALWARE_PROTECTION; feature_uid=…
```

every object from $events.events has similar properties, because they're coming from an API query with pagination, with one query page being a line in the array.

My question : how can I merge all objects from this list as a single PSObject, and keeping the exact same properties ?

Comment: Do you mean a single object or an array of unified objects ? If its a single object, whats the condition that determines which property value from which object is preserved

Comment: Apologies I should have been more specific. the goal is to have an object with 2 properties (total & events). But not in an array, just in a single object

Comment: And the `Events` property would contain all these objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking to group all objects by the `Total` property and create a new unified object that contains all objects in `Events`.

If my assumption is right, you can group them using [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3) and then create a new instance:

```
$newObject = $events | Group-Object Total | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Total  = [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([int[]] $_.Group.Total)
        Events = $_.Group.Events
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! I had no clues about the enumerable. Thank you so much !

Comment: @Douda yay happy to help :) glad this was what you were looking for

Comment: It's the second time you're giving me a hand in 2 days. You're so good at this ! Any recommendation on PS reads ?

Comment: @Douda I think [PSKoans](https://github.com/vexx32/PSKoans) is a great learning tool and it's free. I personally learnt by my own curiosity and tinkering and just being around ppl that know more than me :P

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, ditto on this as well. ***;-}***. You can learn from anyone, anywhere at any level, as long as you are willing to allow yourself to. My philosophy is ABL (always be learning and improving.) Why, because you are never as bad as you think you are, but you'll never be as good as you want to be, because things are always changing, and we must change with them. Once you stop being willing to learn or think you know it all, well, you know.